# fetching mysql data with multi color with php

Tags: php

how can i fetch data from mysql with php and display it in mutliple color....like

```
[gray]first post
[white]second post
[gray]third post
[white]forth post
```

i know `mysql_fetch_array` but how can i display data with multi color like above

Answer (score 2):

You have to loop over your lines, knowing if you are on an "even" or "odd" line *(at least, if you want two colors)*, which can be calculated using the modulo operator.

For instance, as a quick idea, the following code :

```
$arr = array(
  'first',
  'second',
  'third',
  'fourth',
);

$i = 0;
foreach ($arr as $line) {
  $class = ($i%2 ? 'odd' : 'even');
  echo '<div class="' . $class . '">' . htmlspecialchars($line) . '</div>' . "\n";
  $i++;
}
```

Will give this HTML output :

```
<div class="even">first</div>
<div class="odd">second</div>
<div class="even">third</div>
<div class="odd">fourth</div>
```

And now, up to you to configure the two `.odd` and `.even` CSS classes to get the colors you want.

Comment: I'd reverse the modulo: it's a bit weird to have the first line "even" and the second one "odd".

Comment: @sprugman : maybe, yes ^^ doesn't change much, but it might feel more logical ; depends if you consider that "first" line is line 1 or line 0, I suppose

Comment: but what should i use as $arr i.e i has $row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)
did you mean this $row

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this (most of them more sophisticated than this example) but you're seemingly looking for a simple solution.

```
for($c=true; false!==($row=mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)); $c=!$c) {
  $class = $c ? 'even':'odd';
  echo '<div class="', $class, '">', $row['x'], '</div>', "\n";
}
```

`$c ? 'even':'odd';` tests whether $c is true or false and the result is 'even' if it is true and 'odd' if it is false. I.e. $class is either 'even' or 'odd' depending on the value of $c.
The for-loop starts with $c=true (initialization part of the for-loop). At the end of each iteration of the loop `$c=!$c` is executed which flips $c from true->false or false->true, i.e. $c alternates between true and false.

You can also use javascript to let the client add the coloring as an enhancement.
E.g. using [jquery](http://jquery.com/):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      tr.even td { background-color: red; }
      tr.odd td { background-color: blue; }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.pack.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready( function() {
        $('#t1 tr:odd').addClass('even');
        $('#t1 tr:even').addClass('odd');
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table id="t1">
      <tr><td>a</td><td>A</td></tr>
      <tr><td>b</td><td>B</td></tr>
      <tr><td>c</td><td>C</td></tr>
      <tr><td>d</td><td>D</td></tr>
      <tr><td>e</td><td>E</td></tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Itay Moav's and Pascal MARTIN's examples work, but if you have a numeric array you can simplify the code slightly:

```
foreach ($rows as $i => $row){
    $even_odd = ($i%2) ? 'even' : 'odd';
    echo "<tr class='$even_odd'>......";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In the loop

```
$i=0;
foreach ($rows as $row){
  echo '<tr class="color'.($i%2).'">.........';
  $i++;
}
```

in the css

```
.color1{ background-color: white}
.color0{ background-color: silver}
```